# How to rebalance and reclaim disk space after adding a Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra

I have a 12 node cassandra cluster which is high on data load and disc space is almost nearing full capacity. I have expanded the cluster by adding 1 node and planning to add couple more.
I could find that the data load got reduced after adding the new node. However, the disc space has not reduced.
I fear running nodetool repair as this may require additional disc space and the available space may not be sufficient.
There are suggestions to use nodetool cleanup, looks like this will also cause temporary increase in disk space.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCleanup.html

Please suggest if there are better ways to cleanup old data from other nodes to reclaim disc space

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `nodetool cleanup` is the only way you could evict data that a node no longer owns after nodes are added to a cluster in order to reclaim disk space.

In order for `cleanup` to work, it temporarily uses more space since it needs to re-compact SSTables to new ones. This can be problematic if you have really large SSTables that are several GBs in size and don't have a lot of disk space left.

You can workaround this problem for large SSTables which are configured with `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy` by splitting them into smaller files on another server using the `sstablesplit` tool. I've documented the instructions in https://community.datastax.com/questions/6415/. Cheers!

Comment: I get the below error while trying to follow the sstablesplit command. I am running this from a docker container - "WARN  06:13:26 Only 33.570GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
Skipping non sstable file /opt/cassandra"
No valid sstables to split

Comment: Cassandra version is 3.9

Comment: That's an error. It's a warning (`WARN`). You need disk space in order to re-compact files. For example, if you're splitting a 100GB file then you need a minimum 100GB (preferably 110GB) because it needs space to write new files. Cheers!

Comment: After increasing disc space, the warning is gone. But it still fails to recognize the sstable

Comment: /usr/bin/sstablesplit --debug --no-snapshot /opt/cassandra
Skipping non sstable file /opt/cassandra
No valid sstables to split
/usr/bin/sstablesplit --debug --no-snapshot /opt/cassandra/mc-3264-big-Index.db
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown keyspace opt
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:309)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:127)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.openWithoutSSTables(Keyspace.java:110)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.StandaloneSplitter.main(StandaloneSplitter.java:114)

Comment: Should I move these files under cassandra data directory or can it be run from any file location?  root@f0d42c99511e:/opt/cassandra# ls
mc-3264-big-CompressionInfo.db  mc-3264-big-Digest.crc32  mc-3264-big-Index.db       mc-3264-big-Summary.db
mc-3264-big-Data.db             mc-3264-big-Filter.db     mc-3264-big-Statistics.db  mc-3264-big-TOC.txt